# the ajax call not working, why it pass on the action directly?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a form which records the responses on the comments this form linked to the latter, when I click on the save button it goes through the action of the form against me I would like to go through an Ajax call here is: an example of my coded

this is the button which display a form

```
 <div>
         <button th:data-comment-id="${comment.id}"
           th:data-comment-index="'comment'+${itmStat.index}"
              id="replyComment"
                th:onclick="showForm(this.getAttribute('data-comment-index'),this.getAttribute('data-comment-id'));">
         </button>
 </div>
```

this is my form :

```
<div style="display: none">
                            <form class="form-reply-comment" th:object="${form}" method="post"
                                  th:action="@{/comment/save}">
                                <div>
                                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{code}">
                                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{company}">                                       <textarea type="text" id="childId"
                                              th:field="*{comment}"
                                              placeholder="Reply to comment"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button id="btn-save-reply-comment">
                                        Save
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

A ajax call :

```
 $('.form-reply-comment').on('submit',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let formData = $('.form-reply-comment').serialize();
            $.ajax({
        url: "/comment/save",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#childId').val("");

        },
        });
    });
```

what I want to do is to make the ajax call not , and not pass on the action directly
Thnk you for your help

Comment: why "$('.form-reply-comment')" is in each?,
your "on('submit',function(){});" is not working well,
because it is not preventing the default process

Comment: @JovylleBermudez I just edit it to `on.('submit')`, the same probleme,  it was a test cause I have a collection of comments foreach one I have a form reply

Comment: I solved it using `$(document).on('submit','form-reply-comment',function(e)` the form class it wasn't identify in my document